# Por que uma pergunta simples sobre manipular outros processos foi fechada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

A seguinte pergunta foi fechada:

- [Como minimizar uma aplicação em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263106/3635)

Só que tem um porém, independente do que o usuário disse sobre TeamSpeak:

> Estou tentando minimizar o TeamSpeak para a bandeja do sistema.

O comportamento do *SystemTray* não tem haver com o **estado da janela**, segue links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx

O estado da janela só tem os seguintes comportamentos:

- `SW_FORCEMINIMIZE`, `SW_HIDE`, `SW_MAXIMIZE`, `SW_MINIMIZE`, `SW_RESTORE`, `SW_SHOW`, `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`, `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`, `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`, `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE`, `SW_SHOWNA`, `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` e `SW_SHOWNORMAL`

Ou seja aquele icone gerado no SystemTray é uma implementação propria interna dos aplicativos específicos, inclusive eu adicionei isto a resposta:

> Um detalhe importante, não tem como minimizar para o SystemTray, isso depende da aplicação, geralmente aplicações minimizadas que suportam o SystemTray nativamente podem ser configuradas para usar SystemTray no momento em que minimizam, mas nem toda aplicação externa vai ter esse capacidade, ainda sim pode experimentar minimizar.

Resumindo, pra mim a pergunta não necessita de código algum para ser clara, como foi o motivo principal do fechamento:

> marcada como pendente como não está clara o suficiente

Comment: Porque ela não pareceu clara pros votantes, tá escrito na caixa amarela.

Comment: @LINQ entendo, ainda sim estava especificado na resposta, entendo que o votos de fechamento tenham ocorrido antes da minha resposta, mas os ultimos 2 votos não, e também não me preocupo com o motivo do fechamento, pra mim o que foi fechado pode ser reaberto e fechado novamente, basta agirmos como comunidade e não ficarmos levando pro lado pessoal sem necessidade. A questão é que estou clareando aqui o comportamento da "API" do windows.